# How can I parse CSV data from a character vector to extract a data frame?

Tags: r, parsing, csv, dataframe, import-from-csv

The read.table and read.csv functions in R are used to parse a file or URL containing delimited data and produce an R data frame.  However, I already have a character vector that contains the CSV delimited data (using comma and \n as column and record delimiters), so I don't need to read it from a file or URL.  How can I pass this character vector into `read.table`, `read.csv`, or `scan()` without writing it to a file on disk first and reading it back in?  I realize that writing it to disk is possible, but I am looking for a solution that does not require this needless roundtrip and can read data from the character vector directly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use textConnection() to pass the character vector to read.table().  An example:

```
x  <- "first,second\nthird,fourth\n"
x1 <- read.table(textConnection(x), sep = ",")
# x1
     V1     V2
1 first second
2 third fourth
```

Answer found in the [R mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg84834.html).

**2017 EDIT**

Seven years later, I'd probably do it like this:

```
read.table(text = x, sep = ",")
```

Comment: One warning about this approach: `textConnection()` can be very slow as the number of rows increases. At 223k rows, I'm finding it faster to write to a temporary CSV, and read that in. :(

Answer (score 3):

A minor addendum to neilfws's answer.  This wrapper function is great for helping answer questions on stackoverflow when the questioner has placed raw data in their question rather than providing a data frame.

```
textToTable <- function(text, ...)
{
   dfr <- read.table(tc <- textConnection(text), ...)
   close(tc)
   dfr
}
```

With usage, e.g.

```
textToTable("first,second\nthird,fourth\n", sep = ",")
```